# Why can not I debug but execute the code odoo in pycharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, odoo, odoo-12

I'm trying to debug the Odoo source code.

Execution works normally, but when trying to debug the following message appears:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 181.5540.34)

Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)
```

I'm using Odoo 12, PyCharm 2019.1.3 (Professional Edition) and Python 3.6 on Windows 10.

This is the first time I try to debug this Code.

Comment: Try this. Control Panel>Region>Adminstrative>Change system locale>Enable: Beta Use UTF-8

Comment: [As this pic](https://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/142470d1299604320-region-language-change-region-language-administrative-.png?s=8389f570a84d4828fc69e5ed4784831c)

Comment: sorry, I not familiar with Spanish, do you mean its solved?

Comment: It's an issue that some lib in python conflict with Win10. I saw some instance in Chinese community.

Comment: lib name is `locale`.

Comment: Yes my problem is solved. Thanks for your help and for the explanation.

Comment: I can not mark a comment as an answer?

Comment: ok, then I post it. please accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw some instance in the Chinese community.
It's an issue that some lib in python conflict with Win10.
Usually, it's a lib named `locale` conflict with the setting in your system.

`Control Panel>Region>Adminstrative>Change system locale>Enable: Beta Use UTF-8`

As the pic down below.
[image: pic]